# Prevent image rotation into SVG circle on d3 radial tree

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I´m using a d3js simple tree radial graph, and I add extra circle with SVG image on depth 1, but the image is translated and rotated to the circle position.

How can I preserve or rotate image to see as the original position (means vertical mode)?

Here is my dummy code:

```js
var pubs = {
  "name": "AUT-1",
  "children": [{
    "name": "PUB-1",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AUT-11",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-111"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-112"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-12",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-121"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-13",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-131"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-132"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-14",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-141"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "PUB-2",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AUT-21"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-22"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-23"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-24"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-25"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-26"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-27"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-28",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-281"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-282"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-283"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-284"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-285"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-286"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "PUB-3"
  }, {
    "name": "PUB-4",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AUT-41"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-42"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-43",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-431"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-432"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-433"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-434",
        "children": [{
          "name": "ADD-4341"
        }, {
          "name": "ADD-4342"
        }, ]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-44"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "PUB-5",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AUT-51",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-511"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-512"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-513"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-514"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-515"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-516"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-52"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-53"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-54"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-55",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-551"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-552"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-553"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-554"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-56"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-57"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-58"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-59"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-591"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-592"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-593"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-594"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-595"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-596"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "PUB-6",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AUT-61",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-611"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-612"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-613"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-614",
        "children": [{
          "name": "ADD-6141"
        }, {
          "name": "ADD-6142"
        }, ]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-62"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-63"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-64"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-65"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-66"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-67"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-68"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-69"
    }]
  }]
};

var diameter = 800;

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = diameter,
  height = diameter;

var i = 0,
  duration = 350,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([360, diameter / 2 - 80])
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 10) / a.depth;
  });

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

root = pubs;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

//root.children.forEach(collapse); // start with all children collapsed
update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 80;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)

  .style("fill", function(d) {
    console.log(d.depth);
    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
  });

  nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {
      return d.depth == 1;
    })
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", "1.2em")
    .style("fill", "gray")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "circle_" + d.depth
    })
    .attr("id", "circle_group")
    .attr("stroke", "#CCC")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .style("fill", "url(#group_avatar)");

  nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {
      return (d.depth == 1);
    })
    .append("svg:pattern")
    .attr("id", "group_avatar")
    .attr("width", 24)
    .attr("height", 24)
    .attr("patternUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://openclipart.org/image/32px/svg_to_png/168481/avatar-icon-silhouette-1.png")
    .attr("class", "circle_avatar")
    .attr("width", 24)
    .attr("height", 24)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length * 8.5)  + ")"; })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
    })

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length + 50) + ")";
    });

  // TODO: appropriate transform
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "diagonal(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }

  update(d);
}

// Collapse nodes
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

I've added the following code:

```
nodeUpdate.selectAll(".circle_1").attr("transform", function(d) {
  return "rotate(" + (-1 * d.x + 90) + ")";
});
```

This will select all your circles of depth 1 (based on the class of `circle_1`) and "unrotate" them.

```js
var pubs = {
  "name": "AUT-1",
  "children": [{
    "name": "PUB-1",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AUT-11",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-111"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-112"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-12",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-121"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-13",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-131"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-132"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-14",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-141"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "PUB-2",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AUT-21"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-22"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-23"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-24"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-25"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-26"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-27"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-28",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-281"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-282"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-283"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-284"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-285"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-286"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "PUB-3"
  }, {
    "name": "PUB-4",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AUT-41"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-42"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-43",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-431"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-432"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-433"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-434",
        "children": [{
          "name": "ADD-4341"
        }, {
          "name": "ADD-4342"
        }, ]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-44"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "PUB-5",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AUT-51",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-511"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-512"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-513"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-514"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-515"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-516"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-52"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-53"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-54"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-55",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-551"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-552"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-553"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-554"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-56"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-57"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-58"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-59"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-591"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-592"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-593"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-594"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-595"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-596"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "PUB-6",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AUT-61",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AFF-611"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-612"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-613"
      }, {
        "name": "AFF-614",
        "children": [{
          "name": "ADD-6141"
        }, {
          "name": "ADD-6142"
        }, ]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-62"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-63"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-64"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-65"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-66"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-67"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-68"
    }, {
      "name": "AUT-69"
    }]
  }]
};

var diameter = 800;

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = diameter,
  height = diameter;

var i = 0,
  duration = 350,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([360, diameter / 2 - 80])
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 10) / a.depth;
  });

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

root = pubs;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

//root.children.forEach(collapse); // start with all children collapsed
update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 80;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)

  .style("fill", function(d) {
    //console.log(d.depth);
    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
  });

  nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {
      return d.depth == 1;
    })
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", "1.2em")
    .style("fill", "gray")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "circle_" + d.depth
    })
    .attr("id", "circle_group")
    .attr("stroke", "#CCC")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .style("fill", "url(#group_avatar)");

  nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {
      return (d.depth == 1);
    })
    .append("svg:pattern")
    .attr("id", "group_avatar")
    .attr("width", 24)
    .attr("height", 24)
    .attr("patternUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://openclipart.org/image/32px/svg_to_png/168481/avatar-icon-silhouette-1.png")
    .attr("class", "circle_avatar")
    .attr("width", 24)
    .attr("height", 24)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length * 8.5)  + ")"; })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
    });
  

  nodeUpdate.selectAll(".circle_1").attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + (-1 * d.x + 90) + ")";
  });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length + 50) + ")";
    });

  // TODO: appropriate transform
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "diagonal(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }

  update(d);
}

// Collapse nodes
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Note: In the following code:

```
nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {
    return d.depth == 1;
  })
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", "1.2em")
  .style("fill", "gray")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return "circle_" + d.depth
  })
  .attr("id", "circle_group")
  .attr("stroke", "#CCC")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("pointer-events", "none")
  .style("fill", "url(#group_avatar)");
```

You're re-using the id `circle_group`, which technically you shouldn't do, though in this case it's not causing you any issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help , I really appreciate that , and of course I will follow your recommendations